# why my java -jar command can't run in my shell

Tags: java, shell, jar

i run jar to my log:

```
java -jar /opt/ftpcounter/sakura.jar>>/opt/ftpcounter/ftpcounter.log
```

then my log have jar result:

```
2017-11-23 02:09:50,904 [GetSql.java:166][ERROR]:数据库连接异常,请检查地址/账号/密码是否正确
```

this is my sh,want it remind me how jar runed when i use crontab run it:

```
    #!/bin/bash  

#导入JAVA环境变量(根据当前服务器调整)
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8" 
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk8/
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JRE_HOME/lib
export JAVA_HOME JRE_HOME PATH CLASSPATH
#指定Jar所在目录
FTP_HOME=/opt/ftpcounter  
CONFIG=$FTP_HOME/configer.properties 
#开始运行
echo "【`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S`】开始执行数据库导入程序......"  
sed -i "/OVER/ s/=.*/=0/g" $CONFIG  
cd $FTP_HOME && echo "进入目录:$FTP_HOME"  
#执行结果输出到日志
java -jar $FTP_HOME/sakura.jar>>$FTP_HOME/ftpcounter.log 
java -jar $FTP_HOME/sakura.jar && echo "执行sakura.jar完成！" || echo "执行sakura.jar失败！"  
echo "【`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S`】数据库导入程序运行完毕，等待下次执行."
```

then my log skip my jar result,just remind me sussess and fail,that not i want:

```
【2017-11-23_02:16:01】开始执行数据库导入程序...... 
进入目录: 
执行sakura.jar失败！ 
【2017-11-23_02:16:01】数据库导入程序运行完毕，等待下次执行.
```

Answer (score 0):

The jar might not have a Manifest.txt

The following is from Oracle [Setting an Application's Entry Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

**Setting an Application's Entry Point**

If you have an application bundled in a JAR file, you need some way to indicate which class within the JAR file is your application's entry point. You provide this information with the Main-Class header in the manifest, which has the general form:

`Main-Class: classname`

The value classname is the name of the class that is your application's entry point.

Recall that the entry point is a class having a method with signature public static void main(String[] args).

After you have set the Main-Class header in the manifest, you then run the JAR file using the following form of the java command:

`java -jar JAR-name`

The main method of the class specified in the Main-Class header is executed.

**An Example**

We want to execute the main method in the class MyClass in the package MyPackage when we run the JAR file.

We first create a text file named Manifest.txt with the following contents:

`Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass`

Warning: The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.

We then create a JAR file named MyJar.jar by entering the following command:

`jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class`

This creates the JAR file with a manifest with the following contents:

`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass`

When you run the JAR file with the following command, the main method of MyClass executes:

`java -jar MyJar.jar`

**Setting an Entry Point with the JAR Tool**

The 'e' flag (for 'entrypoint') creates or overrides the manifest's Main-Class attribute. It can be used while creating or updating a JAR file. Use it to specify the application entry point without editing or creating the manifest file.
For example, this command creates app.jar where the Main-Class attribute value in the manifest is set to MyApp:

`jar cfe app.jar MyApp MyApp.class`

You can directly invoke this application by running the following command:

`java -jar app.jar`

If the entrypoint class name is in a package it may use a '.' (dot) character as the delimiter. For example, if Main.class is in a package called foo the entry point can be specified in the following ways:

`jar cfe Main.jar foo.Main foo/Main.class`